# "Simulate" trigger for Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have set task with this trigger:
At system start up - After triggered, repeat every 5 minutes indefinitely.

But I can´t restart OS, I need run this task now and I need repeat it for 5 minutes.
This trigger (system start up) is only if OS will crash.

Is possible to activate trigger without reboot?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Try **THIS**]
Go to **create task**-->**Trigger**--> **new**
now it works!!!!